# Count the Date column based on the same month from Mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql

Lets say I have a MySql table with columns empID and date. I want get count of empID where the dates are from the same month. For example if an empID has 4 dates in the table from same month an email should be triggered

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(serverstring))
{
     con.Open();
     string query = "SELECT COUNT(empID) FROM tblnm WHERE empID=@eid date=date";
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", lbleid.Text);
     string cnt = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     var count = Convert.ToInt32(cnt);
     if(count >= 4)
     {
         triggerEmail();
     }
}
```

So the month can any of the coming months but if there is more than or equal to 4 datas with same empID on the any of the months the query should check for it and the email has to be triggered. How can I get it done? Thanks in advance....

Comment: You mean same month as the input parameter, or if at any time in the past they've had records during the same month?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn any date past or future that are in the table. This happens on Page_Load

Comment: Such queries become a lot easier if you use a Calendar table - a table containing eg 20 years of dates with separate columns for year,month, day, week etc.

Comment: If it happens more than once for the same employee, do you want more than one result?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes I dont want to pass date as parameter but I'll be passing empID as parameter.And it will be for single empID which will be passed from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql has the `LAST_DAY()` function you can use in combination with `GROUP BY` / `HAVING` clauses to easily get counts within the same month:

```
SELECT EmpID, LAST_DAY(`Date`) AS Month, COUNT(*) As NumEntries
FROM tblnm 
WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
GROUP BY EmpID, LAST_DAY(`Date`)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

And use it like this:

```
string query = @"
    SELECT EmpID, LAST_DAY(`Date`) AS Month, COUNT(*) As NumEntries
    FROM tblnm 
    WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
    GROUP BY EmpID, LAST_DAY(`Date`)
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4;";

using (var con = new MySqlConnection(serverstring))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lbleid.Text);
    con.Open();
    using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {     
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
           triggerEmail(rdr["EmpID"], (int)rdr["NumEntries"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please edit based on my latest edit? I'm passing empID as a parameter here. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to extract the month number or name from the above query and pass it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(empID)
FROM tblnm
WHERE year(date) = year(@date) and month(date) = month(@date);
```

But I will say, if you want to know which empID has more than 4 entries :

```
SELECT empID, COUNT(*)
FROM tblnm
WHERE year(date) = year(@date) and month(date) = month(@date)
group by empID;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I need to get this done without passing date as parameter.

Comment: Replace `@date` by `curdate()` function.